# why Turbo Code encoder doesn't work if the component codes are recursive but not SYSTEMATIC?

Tags: coding-theory

Doesn't work in my sense is that it will not give a desired performance or in other words doesn't give inter-leaver performance gain?

---

I know that component codes should be Recursive Systematic Codes. I Knew the reason why it doesn't work if the component codes are Non Recursive. But what is the need for Systematic??

---

[Editor's comment: I took the liberty of moving this comment by the OP here, because that IMHO shows that he has thought about this. JL]

Comment: I know that component codes should be Recursive Systematic Codes. I Knew the reason why it doesn't work if the component codes are Non Recursive. But what is the need for Systematic??

Comment: @martini,Tunk-Fey, Daniel, amwhy, Hakim: Just because you have no knowledge on Coding Theory doesn't mean this question is off-topic. perhaps you are in the wrong area.

Comment: I agree that this question is on-topic. However, it would be helpful if you added some background information into the question so it's readable by a wider audience. As someone familiar with some coding theory, but not turbo codes in particular, I had to look up "component codes" and "recursive" in order to understand what you were asking. (Unfortunately I don't know the answer to your question.)

Comment: I agree that this question is on-topic. I added your comment to the question body, because there it helps readers to see that you have thought about it. Also it helps pinpointing the type of answer that you seek. Probably further improvements are needed for this to attract enough reopen votes.

Comment: For example, I'm a bit curious. What kind of a turbo code did you try? The turbo codes (interleavers in particularly) are usually designed in a way to steer clear from "obvious patterns" of low Hamming weight words. May be you accidentally introduced such words? They usually result in high error floors and such (I think - my mileage on turbo codes is kinda low).

Comment: well, assume a Rate=1/3 Turbo encoder (parallel concatenated convolutional code through some pseudo-random inter-leaver). Assume inter-leaver block length is very long to produce a long code from a small memory convolutional code. The question is if the component encoders are Recursive (transfer function is rational- aka feedback in the encoder) but not systematic, why does the resultant concatenated code is not as good as the turbo encoder with recursive systematic component codes?

Comment: It may depend on the specific interleaver and the transfer function. If you meddle with the transfer function you probably need to change the interleaver. And some transfer functions (most notably polynomial ones as you yourself observed) are worse for turbo design. Could you give examples of specific transfer function that performs poorly, and a good one you compared it to. Probably need the interleaver too, but it may be difficult to say, why a given interleaver is bad.

Comment: If you don't use a systematic code, what are the three streams that you work with. Normally these are A) systematic (=input), B) check bits of the non-interleaved code, C) check bits of the interleaved code. These can be iteratively decoded with SOVA. A+B in every other half-iteration and A+C in every other. If the two coding methods that you use don't produce identical A-streams, then it takes more work to use the extrinsic information from the other half-iteration. I guess it is still possible, but it looks like you might lose some. Can you please describe your experiment in more detail.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Actually I was not doing any simulations or something ,I was just doing literature survey on turbo codes. I just got this doubt while reading from the book "Turbo Codes: Principles and Applications by Barka Vucetic". I am a grad student working for my PhD. Anyway I am very happy to get a reply from the a Prof in Coding theory. I love this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A turbo code uses a convolutional code (of, say, rate $\frac{1}{2}$) to create two different codewords $C_1$ and $C_2$ from the given block $D$ of $K$ data bits.  Note 
that $C_1$ and $C_2$
are *terminated* codewords, that is, input $D$ is followed by zeroes to clear out the encoder buffers, and so the codewords are of length *slightly* more than 
$2K$ bits. $C_1$ encodes the block $D$ as is, that is, the information symbols
are followed by buffer-clearing zeroes, while $C_2$ encodes
a *permutation* $\pi(D)$ of the data block as the information symbols (also followed by the buffer-clearing zeroes).

Now, if the convolutional code is *non-systematic*, it is necessary to transmit
both $C_1$ and $C_2$ over the channel, and so a little more than $4K$ bits 
are transmitted to send $K$ information bits over the channel. The effective code
rate is thus $\frac{1}{4}$. On the other hand, if the code in use is
*systematic*, then the two codewords are effectively of the form 
$C_1 = (D, P_1)$
and $C_2 = (\pi(D), P_2)$ where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the parity bit blocks of slightly
more than $K$ bits each. What is transmitted over the channel is 
effectively $(D, P_1, P_2)$ because it is not really necessary to 
transmit both $D$ and $\pi(D)$ over the channel. The decoder, who
knows the permutation $\pi(\cdot)$,  can construct $\pi(D)$ from the received
data block. The effective rate is thus $\frac{1}{3}$.

Of course, what the decoder reconstructs is $\pi(\hat{D})$ where
$\hat{D}$ is the *received* data block which may differ from $D$ in a few
positions. Now, as the turbo decoding proceeds, the two decoders for the
two received words $(\hat{D}, \hat{P}_1)$ and $(\pi(\hat{D}), \hat{P}_2)$
create estimates of the data block $D$ and each uses what the other
thinks is the best estimate of the data in improving its own estimate.
This "message-passing" is the crux of the turbo decoding algorithm.
Of course, all this could be done with *nonsystematic* codes as well,
but it is more complicated, and there is also the rate penalty to be
considered.

In short, the reason for using systematic codes is that they offer
significantly better code rates than nonsystematic codes.

Comment: why did you consider that the convolutional encoder is non-recursive? you cannot drive a recursive encoder to all zero state by just giving input a all zero sequence.

Comment: However, it answers the question.

Comment: driving both the recursive encoders simultaneously to zero state and that too connected through an interleaver !! I don't think it is possible with just giving all zero input sequence.